# ClassLoader only working from classpath and not url

Tags: java, classloader

So I'm trying to load a file from a link and run it in memory. Everything is working is working fine but only when the .jar is in the classpath of the project. My code is as follows:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;

public class Main {

    public static URL getURL(String string) throws MalformedURLException {
        try {
            return new URL(string);
        } catch (MalformedURLException x) { return new URL("file:" + string); }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String jarLocation = "http://www.google.ca/file.jar";
        URL url = new URL(jarLocation);
        getURL(jarLocation);
        JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(url.openStream());
        String main = jis.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
        String classpaths[] = jis.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Class-Path").split(" ");
        for (String classpath: classpaths) {
            getURL(classpath);
        }
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader((new URL[0]));
        Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(main);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
        Method m = cls.getMethod("main", new Class[]{new String[0].getClass()});
        m.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});

    }

}
```

The problem is that no matter what the link is, .jar will only run if it is in the classpath of the project. **How can I load the file from a link instead of from having it in the classpath?**

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are *not* passing your .jar URLs to the URLClassloader. In your code it takes an empty array, so I don't know how to load classes from your jar file.

Here is an example of how you can modify your code to pass the jar urls to the URLClassloader:

```
public class Main {

    public static URL getURL(String string) throws MalformedURLException {
        try {
            return new URL(string);
        } catch (MalformedURLException x) { return new URL("file:" + string); }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String jarLocation = "http://www.google.ca/file.jar";
        List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        URL url = new URL(jarLocation);
        urls.add(getURL(jarLocation));
        JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(url.openStream());
        String main = jis.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
        String classpaths[] = jis.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Class-Path").split(" ");
        for (String classpath: classpaths) {
            urls.add(getURL(classpath));
        }
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));
        Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(main);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
        Method m = cls.getMethod("main", new Class[]{new String[0].getClass()});
        m.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});

    }

}
```